# Use a method from one form in another, in the same project?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, listbox, generic-list

I've got two forms, one called Form1 and the other called Admin. I have a method in Form1 to return a list of items. Is it possible to call this method in the second form, Admin? And if so, how?

It makes use of a Generic List.

Here is the code for Form1:

```
private String displayProducts()
    {
        lstProducts.Items.Add("ID\tItem\tCategory\t\tPrice\tStock\n");
        lstProducts_Load();
        for (int i = 0; i < products.Count(); i++)
        {
            lstProducts.Items.Add(products.ElementAt(i).Display() + "\n");
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: .Net member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: @SLaks Also called as PascalCase

Comment: A form is a *class*.  Clearly you already know how to use members of a class, you had no problem using the Items property of the list.  It works the *exact* same way with a form.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are regular classes.
You can call any public method on a form as long as you have an instance of it.

You can make your method `public`, then pass an instance of the first form to the second form.

Comment: yeah, i thought of that just after I posted the question but it doesnt seem to work. Ive made the method public, but in the second form, I call "displayProduct()" and "Form1.displayProduct()" but no luck.

Comment: @EmmetMcLaughlin: You need an **instance**, just like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your `Form1` method `Public`. Then you can call it from an instance of `Form1`.

i.e.

```
public String displayProducts()
```

Then in `Admin` **Form**

```
var myForm = new Form1();
var returnValue = myForm.displayProducts();
```

P.S. If you think you'll need the `displayProducts` in many places, better to separate it out into a `Utility` class.

Comment: Creating a new instance won't do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of ways of doing this. SLaks and Shiva are both 100% correct. Make an instance of Form1 and call the public displayProducts functions.

That is the answer to your question but i think i know what you are trying to achieve.

If you do not want to do that create a simple model to store your products in a static class

```cs
public static class Products
{
    public static List<String> lstProducts = new List<String>();

    public static void AddProducts(string product)
    {
        lstProducts.Add(product);
    }

    public static string DisplayProducts()
    {
        //return whatever you want lstproducts
        return "";
    }
}
```

now you can use this in Form1 to add Products like

```
Products.AddProduct("Product1");
```

and get the display the products in Admin by using

```
Products.DisplayProducts();
```

But, this is unnecessary and elaborate. I just mentioned this clearly bad code as a model class to store your data that you want to share between your Forms.